# Semantic exceptions from Hibernate when SQL hits constraints

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate 5.2 with Postgre 9.5. 
My DB schema has several constraints. Is there any "easy" possibility to expose constraint name to end user? Imagine I have unique constraint

```
ALTER TABLE JobTable
  ADD CONSTRAINT JobTableJobStatusEnum
CHECK (jobStatus IN ('JobSubmitted', 'JobRunning', 'JobFailed', 'JobKilled', 'JobSucceeded'));
```

I want to re-throw something like 
*ConstraintViolationException("Can't execute operation. Your query breaks JobTableJobStatusEnum")*

Yeah, It won't make any sense to business users, but other developers would understand the problem. I can grab constraint def from DB and put it into exception message also.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have constraints information in exception - stacktrace.

If you need to wrap original exception and add something custom (it's not so custom it's just change exception message), you can catch ConstraintViolationException (or exception and check that it's caused by ConstraintViolationException with apache commons-lang ExceptionUtils util)

```
catch(ConstraintViolationException e){
    Strign message = e.getCause().getMessage();
    .....
    work with message
    String detailMessage = String.format("Can't execute operation. Your query breaks %" , message);  
    throw new ConstraintViolationException(detailMessage , e);
}
```

For **mysql** (for Postgre  should be something similar) it looks like

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException:
>   Duplicate entry 'testemail@gmail.com' for key
>   'UK_n7ihswpy07ci568w34q0oi8he'

If you know format message for ConstraintViolation in your db , you can get constraint name from exception message method.

Comment: Yeah, I took a look at it, but parsing exception and analyzing stacktrace is booring. I'm looking for some library/extension.

Comment: you already had this exception - MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException with all information. just get from exception.getMessage details about constraint.